# Can not use where and groupby at a time in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

LeaveJournalTable

```
emp_code  emp_name  leave_code  leave_des     leave_debit  leave_credit

     11        X        AL       openingbalace       5              0

     11        X        EL        openingbalace      8              0

     11        X        EL        allowance          10             0

     11        X        AL       allowance          10              0
     11        X        AL         Taken             0              2
     11        X        AL         Taken             0              3
```

I want to create a query in Hibernate as

```
Query query = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from LeaveOpenningJournal WHERE empCode = :empCode and " + "empName = :empName and " +  "companyCode = :companyCode")
```

As well as I want to sum leave_credit field GroupBy(leave_code,leave_des)

Comment: Why you cannot use them? Could you show error message and something like that?

Comment: Need suggestions to do where claues + groupby and sum at a time

Comment: Try query like this: SELECT *,SUM(leave_credit) FROM  LeaveOpenningJournal j WHERE emp_Code = "11" AND emp_Name = "x" GROUP BY leave_code,leave_des

Comment: I do agree but how to write this in hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

Please check this code:

```
Query listQuery = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT *,SUM(leave_credit) FROM LeaveOpenningJournal j WHERE mpCode = :empCode AND empName = :empName GROUP BY leave_code,leave_des");
listQuery.setParameter("empCode", "11");
listQuery.setParameter("empName", "x");
List<Object[]> parentChildMap = listQuery.list();
```

Which simply set the `parameter` and fetch result into the `list`.

Comment: Ok..Thanks indeed..I will try according to your suggestions.

Comment: Why I will write this ? -- List<Object[]> parentChildMap = listQuery.list(); @PVR

Comment: To store your results into the list.